# JPA Persist ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa

This seems super simple but I can't find a quick solution.

I have a super simple relationship. I have a USER table with three columns, a generated ID, a VARCHAR name, and a foreign key to a HOMETOWN table with two columns - a generated ID and a VARCHAR value. Super simple.

So I'm assuming something typical like this in my UserEntity:

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "HOMETOWN_ID")
  private Hometown hometown;
```

The issue is that a new USER comes in as json via {"name" : "William Burroughs", "hometown" : "Portland, OR"} and what I really want on my UserEntity is a #setHometown(String) method.

My only issue with this is that it seems like my UserEntity will require an EntityManager instance and the setHometown method will need to be transactional, seeing if a Hometown of "Portland, OR" exists, persisting it if it doesn't, and then setting this.hometown to whatever I found or persisted. You see, "Portland, OR" may or may not exist in HOMETOWN already.

Can this be right? Seems like a lot of work for something so simple, and I'd prefer my entities to not require instances of EntityManager.

I feel like I'm making this harder than it needs to be and missing the super simple solution. Also note that it is just a String that I can creating a foreign key reference to.

If you need more data please let me know and I will update this post.

**UPDATE**

*I suppose what bothers me is that I would prefer if a client of User not have to know if the implementation of #setHometown stores a string to a column in USER or a reference to a row in HOMETOWN. If I ever change things schema-wise all code that uses UserEntry must change. I guess this would be another argument for using a DTO/POJO and service layer that hides JPA and DAO related stuff. You'd think JPA would abstract away simple relationships and common patterns like these so that a String field in an object can migrate to or from a table column or foreign key reference.*

Using SQL this would be a simple stored proc starting with an INSERT...RETURNING and a SELECT if error -- all encapsulated in a single stored proc call. With JPA it is pretty difficult to shield the code client from my implementation choices and I have to do something like:

```
@Transactional
public void save(User user, String name) {
    Hometown hometown = new Hometown(name);
    try {
        saveHometown(hometown);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        TypedQuery<Hometown> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT h FROM Hometown h WHERE h.name = :name", Hometown.class);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        hometown = query.getSingleResult();
    }

    user.setHometown(hometown);
    getEntityManager().persist(user);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
protected void saveHometown(final Hometown hometown) {
    getEntityManager().persist(hometown);
}
```

Which is pretty complicated for a simple relationship like this. If I wanted to query first and persist if it doesn't exist then I'd have to do that in a loop or create a table lock. Really? That's the simplest approach for @ManyToOne relationships where the foreign key may or may not exist? You could have a ton of these for City, State, etc. Ah well, such is life I guess. But I swear there must be a simple approach, no?

Comment: I think you should make a transactional service class that handle your string and load the right hometown from database or create a new if not exists. Than add the new/loaded hometown to the user. I think a entitymanager in a entity is a bad practice.

Comment: Alright, so there is no simple solution in JPA that just allows me, for example, to user.setHometown(new Hometown("Portland, OR")) without having to care if Hometown has already been inserted or not. I will just have to do the heavy lifting in my DAO. I'll probably make it a stored proc that my DAO calls instead of using EntityManager#persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could simplify a bit your code, to have something like this

```
@Transactional
public void save(User user, String name) {
    Hometown hometown = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT h FROM Hometown h WHERE h.name = :name", Hometown.class).setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
    if (hometown == null) {
        hometown = new Hometown(name);
    }

    user.setHometown(hometown);
    getEntityManager().persist(user);
}
```

And, you just need to set `cascade` from `User` to `Hometown`

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOMETOWN_ID")
private Hometown hometown;
```

For these situations, we usually have `findOrCreate` methods, that return existing entity or create a new one if it doesn't exist. These are then reused wherever needed.

```
public Hometown findOrCreateHometown(String name) {
    Hometown hometown = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT h FROM Hometown h WHERE h.name = :name", Hometown.class).setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
    if (hometown == null) {
        hometown = new Hometown(name);
    }
    return hometown;
}
```

And your save() method would look like this

```
@Transactional
public void save(User user, String name) {
    Hometown hometown = findOrCreateHometown(name);

    user.setHometown(hometown);
    getEntityManager().persist(user);
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm worried that if I don't persist hometown first that I could have a locking issue if multiple servers are accessing the database. But other than that this is what I'm doing now. I'll still have to have a DTO because ultimately a user of this layer should be able to just user.setHometown("Portland, OR").

Comment: @user1888440 Well, it's possible that you could have concurrency issues. What you could do is to add one `@Version` field to `Hometown` entity, that would take care of locking. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking)